# Solve: $ \dfrac{x}{k_1} + \dfrac{y}{k_2}=z $ when $ x+y \neq z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $\gcd(x,y,z)>1$, any hint on how to find all the non-zero pairs $(k_1, k_2) \in \mathbb{Z^2} $ such that $ \dfrac{x}{k_1} + \dfrac{y}{k_2}=z $ when $ x+y \neq z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the unknowns are $k_1,k_2$ I'll call those $x,y$ and rename your $x,y,z$ as $a,b,c$ so the equation with these variables and constants is
$$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}=c. \tag{1}$$
I don't know why you have the explicit assumption that $\gcd(a,b,c)>1$, since one may divide equation $(1)$ by that gcd and get an equivalent equation. Anyway, after multiplying through by $xy$ and moving things to one side you get $cxy-ax-by=0,$ and multiplying this by $c$ and factoring (after adding $ab$ to each side), you have
$$(cx-a)(cy-b)=ab. \tag{2}$$
Now if $ab \neq 0$ you can see $(2)$ has only finitely many integer pair solutions $(x,y)$ which may be obtained by factoring $ab$ in all possible ways into two factors, setting the two factors on the left of $(2)$ to these (in either order), and seeing which choices give integers for $x,y.$ In case $ab=0$ the equation becomes a bit trivial. For example $a=0$ means it's $b/y=c$ for which there is at most one $y$ and $x$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @coffemath, Thanks for your input. Would the result be any different if the equation was diophantine? The reason why I am asking is because I forgot to mention that this equation was.

Comment: @Andy -- To me, diophantine just means one wants integer solutions. And my answer is about finding all such integer solutions, so it seems it is "diophantine" already.